# UltimateListCtrl set method not working

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm working with `wxPython` and I'm trying to set the background colour of a specific item in `UltimateListCtrl`. When I set the text for a specific item, like this:

```
list.SetItemText(1,"something")
```

This works without any problem. However, when I try the same with `SetItemBackgroundColour`, for example, like this:

```
list.SetItemBackgroundColour(1,'#0000FF')
```

I get a strange error that I don't know how to fix:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\DeVIDE-RE\python\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\w
x\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 6891, in OnPaint
    enabled = theLine.GetItem(0, CreateListItem(line, 0)).IsEnabled()
  File "C:\Program Files\DeVIDE-RE\python\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\w
x\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 4000, in GetItem
    return item.GetItem(info)
  File "C:\Program Files\DeVIDE-RE\python\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\w
x\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 3079, in GetItem
    if self._attr.HasTextColour():
  File "C:\Program Files\DeVIDE-RE\python\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\w
x\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 1183, in HasTextColour
    return self._colText.Ok()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Ok'
```

Which is really strange because `SetItemText` works fine. I checked the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html) but I could not understand why it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a valid [Color](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Colour.html#Colour) object in [SetItemBackgroundColour](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html#lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour) instead of color string.

```
blue = Color(0, 0, 255)
list.SetItemBackgroundColour(1, blue)
```